# codeigniter: controller function to load view and process data submitted

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a gap in understanding Controllers utilization even after visiting the documentation multiple times. I have the following:

```
class Membership extends CI_Controller 
{


    /*Load the login view first assuming user is member*/
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    /*if not member, load register view*/
    public function register()
    {
        $this->load->view('register');
    }

    /*view to recover user credentials*/
    public function recover()
    {
        $this->load->view('recover');
    }

    public function enroll_user()
    {
        /*Retrieve post parameters*/
        $fullname = $this->input->post('fullname');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $mobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
        $home = $this->input->post('home');
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $confirmPassword = $this->input->post('cpassword');
    }

}
```

now example when user clicked on Register Now link on the main page, the register() function should load the view. But after he completes the form and submit it, to which function should I submit it? Does this mean I have to create two functions per functionality, one to load the view (register.php) and the second one to handle the operation of that function (enroll_user)?

Comment: yeah obviously you need to do like that only............

Comment: I would submit the register page to itself. Do all your validation there before moving on to another function/page if it is successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in just one shot

```
public function register()
{
    $post = $this->input->post();
    if($post){
        // do other stuff here
        // you can load view here too if validation fails
    }else{
        $this->load->view('register');
    }
}
```

And in you form use this

```
echo form_open(current_url());
```

Comment: This is excellent approach. I prefer to have a single function handle both functionalities. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your register.php put the action of the form to memebership/enroll_user so when the user submits the registration form the action will be submited to enroll_user function and it will take care of the registration etc.

You need two functions, one for displaying the registration form and other for handling the submitted data. You can do it using one controller but its good practice to do it in two controllers because it will be easier for you to find out which function is doing what later.